# Accessing data in callback function

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, typescript, google-geocoder

I have a function for geocoding an address that returns the name of the city of the same address

```
  // geocode the given address
  geocodeAddress(address, callback) {
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          results[0].address_components.forEach(arrAddress => {
            if (arrAddress.types[0] == "locality") {
              callback(arrAddress.long_name);
            }
          })
        } else {
          console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
      });
    });
  };
```

when I call that function and want to print the city name it is printed 'undefined' from the code line below the geocodeAddress function and after that is printed properly city name

```
this.geocodeAddress(this.offerAddress, data => {
  this.hostCity = data;
  console.log(this.hostCity);
});
console.log(this.hostCity);
```

I was trying to add some timeout before second console.log function but without any success

therefore, I'm interested how to access this value after returning data from geocoder because I need to use this data for storing in database and if I try to store like this

```
    this.geocodeAddress(this.offerAddress, data => {
            this.hostCity = data;
            this.service.addData({"address": this.offerAddress, "city": this.hostCity}, "/data")
                .subscribe(data => {
                  this.router.navigate(['list']);
                })
          });
```

it store data but router.navigate not working properly

so I need solution for accessing hostCity outside of geocodeAddress callback function, or how to properly call some another function inside this geocodeAddress callback function

Comment: What do you mean by this: "router.navigate not working properly"?

Comment: it navigate url to list, but template view is not list template, it's still adding form template. And i tried call another function for opening error dialog "this..confirmDialog(ErrorDialog, "Something wrong");". It opens dialog but without message, and if i call this functions outside geocodeAddress callback function, everything works properly

Comment: In addition to processing the data inside of the `geocodeAddress` callback, change `function (results, status) { ... }` for `(results, status) => { ... }` to preserve the value of `this` with an arrow function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using TypeScript, you can make your `geocodeAddress` method return a `Promise`, instead of using callbacks, and then use `async/await`:

```
async geocodeAddress(address): Promise<string[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
           var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
           geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
               if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                   const result: string[] = [];
                   results[0].address_components.forEach(arrAddress => {
                       if (arrAddress.types[0] == "locality") {
                           result.push(arrAddress.long_name);
                       }
                   });
                   resolve(results);
               } else {
                   console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                   reject(status);
               }
           });
       });
    });
};
```

Now, this function returns an array with the long names of all the addresses you were seeking. To use it:

```
const data: string[] = await this.geocodeAddress(this.offerAddress);
this.hostCity = data[0];
// do whatever you want now
```

This way you get the benefits of asynchronous programming, with the simplicity of synchronous one.

Comment: Why answer this instead of directing the OP to the cannonical async reference question?  It doesn't matter if the OP is using typescript or not.  What matters is that the OP doesn't quite understand how async programming works.

Comment: this solution has helped me. Thank you